# What is the store in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-mvc

I don't understand what is it. Please give me a simple explanation.

What is the store in MVC in ExtJS 4?

Comment: In the future, please apply some research effort before asking a question. This is covered fully in basic ExtJS documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into Ext's [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)?

> The Store class encapsulates a client side cache of Model objects.

(if a model is a row the store is a table...)

Answer (score 0):

What CD says is true. A store is used to connect data to Grids, Comboboxes, Treegrids, ... It stores the Models.